# how to get number of last migration run in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to debug my app on heroku and it seems that one or more migrations didn't run. Without going through each migration manually I'm trying to figure out which migration was the last one that was run.

environment: rails, postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from terminal:

```
 heroku pg:psql --app app_name db_name
 select * from schema_migrations;
```

look for the last entry

Another way... From terminal

```
 heroku run console --app app_name
 class SchemaMigration<ActiveRecord::Base
 end
```

then just write

```
 SchemaMigration.last
```